# Finding number of arrangements on a shelf with one book of a kind in middle

Tags: combinations

There are 6 Novels and 3 Dictionaries. There are to be made arrangements of books in a Shelf consisting of 4 Novels and 1 Dictionary, such that Dictionary is always in the middle.

I tried to do this by:  There should be 2 novels to the left of dictionary and 2 to the right i.e.  6C2 and out of remaining 4C2, and dictionaries can be arranged as 3C1.

So total arrangements: 6C2 * 4C2 * 3C1 = 15*6*3 = 270?
Is my reasoning correct? Can you tell me where I am wrong, Since the answer is incorrect. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the novels distinct? Does the order of the novels matter?

Comment: @Keatinge order doesn't matter.

Comment: In an arrangement, order does matter.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I see, I will keep that in mind. So, I just have to use the permutations formula? 6P4 * 3?

Comment: @H.Ahmed  Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select $1$ dictionary from $3$ in $^3C_1$ ways

Select $4$ novels from $6$ novels in $^6C_4$ ways

Since you chose $4$ novels from $6$, now you can arrange those $4$ novels in $4!$ ways.

Since the dictionary should be in middle $NNDNN$ is the arrangement

$$^6C_4\times^3C_1\times4!\times1!=1080\mbox{ ways.}$$

Comment: is the 4! the arrangement of novels among themselves?

Comment: Yes, $4!$ is the arrangement of novels among themselves. See the edit